# What the differences in properties listed using get-member or not

Tags: powershell, object

To list the properties of a WMI object I used to just print the object in a console like I do with my homemade objects

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
```

That gives me six properties

But if I use Get-Member

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Get-Member
```

I get a bunch of properties and methods

What's the difference ? Are the properties listed only with Get-Member are private or something ?

Also, how can I have the list of those multiple properties with their value shown ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two. `Get-Member` is showing you a list of all public available member types (you can view any additional ones with the `-Force` switch) while the default output is dictated by a custom PowerShell view file that applies per object.

You can get a list of the ones built in with: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $PSHOME -Filter *.Format.ps1xml`

You can view all properties for an object like so: `Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property *`

You can lean more about Format files either [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-5.1) or in the console `Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml`